# Find point coordinates on a plane

Tags: javascript, geometry, point

Could you help me please find coordinates of point on a plane?

[image]

I try to find coordinates of the point.

Comment: What have you tried? Any code?

Comment: As far as I understand, `y = 440.5`. So: `x = 543 - sqrt(250^2-(250-440.5)^2)`

Answer (score 0):

If working with JavaScript, you would employ Math.sin() and Math.cos()

- If you imagine a unit circle (a circle with radius 1),
- and a straight line A starting from the circle's center going towards the
  edge,
- and you know the line A's angle (in radians). Or the angle in degrees to a reference line which points straight right (on your drawing, the reference line would be +90 degrees to the one which shows radius), in which case if line A is in the top half of the circle the angle would be positive, while if in the bottom half of the circle (like your drawing) the angle would be negative.

Of course, if you only have the angle in degrees, you would have to convert it to radians before passing it to sine and cosine functions. It is a simple operation, you can find many examples online:

```
function degrees_to_radians(degrees)
{
  var pi = Math.PI;
  return degrees * (pi/180);
}
```

Then `Math.sin(angleInRadians)` would tell you the Y location of the spot where line intersects the circle, while `Math.cos(angleInRadians)` would tell you the X location. Both X and Y would be relative to the circle center.

And, since the result is for the unit circle, you would also have to multiply both X and Y with actual radius (250). And then add circle's center location (543,250) to get the actual world coordinates of the point.

`X = (X * 250) + 543` and `Y = (Y * 250) + 250`

Hope that helped, you can use Google image search to get some sine and cosine drawings if you're not getting clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Formula:
`x = R * cos(a1) = R * sqrt(1 - ((y + ∆y) / R)^2)`

Solution:

```
let delta = 466.5 - 440.5;
let x = 250 * Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(466.5 + delta) / 250, 2));
```